# Any placeholder rules or keybinding commands to select a pair of characters in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, key-bindings, brackets, vscode-keybinding

```
{
    "key": "cmd+;",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
    "args": { "snippet": "_${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1_$2" }
}
```

A block of code above manages to create a pair of underscores `_` when I press `cmd + ;` on the vscode editor. I put this into the `keybinding.json` and it works fine. The problem is, ***the editor doesn't select the underscores*** just like a various type of brackets do such as `()`, `[]` and `{}`.

Let me explain more detail with `.gif`.

[image]

The `.gif` shows that the pair of square brackets `[]` are selected (grouped) with *a small semi-transparent box* **after** the `[]` are inserted. This eventually allows the users to delete a pair of brackets only 1 backspace if they don't need it anymore, giving them to save a lot of time to delete it.

I want to make my editor selects the pair of underscores `_` like the square brackets `[]` on the above `.gif` shows. I believe there are some ways to resolve this but I can't find them anywhere else.

Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .gif shows that the pair of square brackets [] are selected (grouped) with a small semi-transparent box after the [] are inserted. This eventually allows the users to delete a pair of brackets only 1 backspace if they don't need it anymore, giving them to save a lot of time to delete it.

That's togglable via the `editor.matchBrackets` setting, and only works when a language support extension for the current editor's language mode registers such brackets in their [language configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide).

But as a user, you can also configure language brackets via the `editor.language.brackets` setting. Ex.

```json
"[plaintext]": {
    "editor.language.brackets": [
        ["_","_"],
    ],
},
```

For reasons I don't know, VS Code will accept this and add some bracket features like automatic closing "bracket" when typing the opening "bracket", and automatic closing "bracket" deletion on deleting the opening "bracket", but it won't do matching bracket outlines for underscores. If you're really concerned about that, you should [raise an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Sorry for late response. It was night time in my area and I've just checked your answer. The pair of arbitrary characters what I have set now can remove with 1 backspace, but another problem occurred. This feature only works when I insert them manually. For example, if I put the pair of `_` by pressing `Shift + -`, I can delete the pair. But when I put the pair by pressing `cmd + ;`, the editor deletes only last character of the pair.

Comment: @PhewphewMathew it's standard behaviour that manually deleting the closing one will not auto-delete the opening one.

Comment: I guess I have to get on with it. Thank you for your answer.